# Quartz on one machine with two different JVMs?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I want to configure Quartz so that It can be run on two different JVMs on the same machine.

Anyone has ideas how to do that ?

Comment: I can't understand why spinning up one instane per JVM is a problem for you; do you need routing of events or some other inter-VM communication?

Comment: I want to group the tasks. Basically say Xgroups run on one JVM and Y groups run on the second JVM. The question is - is it possible to run two quartz instances on two different JVMs on one machine ? OR by default with two intanceIDs , quartz schedular going to start  differnt JVMs?  Right now I am not considering anything .. related to routing of events or intercommunication.

Comment: Again, will simply emitting tasks only for one group per JVM not work for you? If inapplicale, look into Apache Camel with some kind of message queue for routing and filtering.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that. I can even recommend running several Quartz instances in their own JVM on one machine. If you use different table prefixes in each you get performance improvement because the database locks are independent. You have to create the Quartz tables with each of the prefixes.

```
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix=qrtz_
```

Or you can use different instance names if you do not care about Quartz performance:

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName=JVM1
```

In this case, you just use the tables with the "quartz_" prefix like you would with one Quartz JVM.